# Google Search Result for Songs on Youtube

Tags: google-search

When I search "hello" on Google, on the very top I get a nice and large player with additional information below it. [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=hello&oq=hello&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i61.13190j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Well, I want to do the same for the songs we publish to Youtube. Right now they appear as small thumbnails in the search result. [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=adele+youtube&oq=adele+youtube&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0l4.1896j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

What do I need to do? Should I create a web page with some specific markup?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, google controls how these videos are displayed on the site and you have no power over that. Unless the song has had millions of views, it's unlikely they will be displayed as you wish.